# SPIA::spia function output

Tags: r

I asked this question on Bioconductor since it was specific to the SPIA package, but haven't received a reply so I'm posting it here to reach a wider audience.

I downloaded the 134 Malus domestica ('mdm') pathways using the KEGGREST package and successfully made the spia data using the makeSPIAdata() function. I'm usng this library to evaluate pathways for two different apples, HoneyCrisp and Cripps Pink. Then, I called the spia() function, and after it completed it only showed 10 pathways that were 'Done.'

> length(dir(mydir)) #Directory containing 134 Malus kgml/xml pathway files.
>      [1] 134

In spia (), my spia input vectors 'de' and 'all' contained 243 unique probesets, and I took the mean logFC for each probeset. This dataset was a subset of the topTable limma result of adj.P.Value < 0.001. Below is the run for HoneyCrisp apples (HC).

```
res<-spia(de=DE_malus_HC, all=entrez_only, organism="mdm", nB = 2000,   
pathids = NULL, data.dir="./", combine = 'fisher', plots = TRUE)

Done pathway 1 : RNA transport..
Done pathway 2 : RNA degradation..
Done pathway 3 : MAPK signaling pathway - plant..
Done pathway 4 : Plant hormone signal transduct..
Done pathway 5 : Sulfur relay system..
Done pathway 6 : SNARE interactions in vesicula..
Done pathway 7 : Autophagy..
Done pathway 8 : Protein processing in endoplas..
Done pathway 9 : Plant-pathogen interaction..
Done pathway 10 : Circadian rhythm - plant..> 

res[ , -12] #Showing RES for HoneyCrisp Apples
Name    ID pSize NDE pNDE          tA    pPERT        pG pGFdr pGFWER      
Status
1              MAPK signaling pathway - plant 04016     4   4    1   
24.29737166 0.160 0.4532130     1      1 Activated
2           Plant hormone signal transduction 04075    14  14    1 
11.93279398 0.292 0.6514524     1      1 Activated
3                    Circadian rhythm - plant 04712     3   3    1  
9.17881852 0.440 0.8012314     1      1 Activated
4                  Plant-pathogen interaction 04626     2   2    1  
0.02234003 0.987 0.9999151     1      1 Activated
5 Protein processing in endoplasmic reticulum 04141     1   1    1    
0.00000000    NA 1.0000000     1      1 Inhibited
```

I then used the 'mdm' library to evaluate a DE set for Cripps Pink (CP) apples...

```
res<-spia(de=DE_malus_CP, all=entrez_only_CP, organism="mdm", nB = 2000,   
pathids = NULL, data.dir="./", plots = TRUE)

Done pathway 1 : RNA transport..
Done pathway 2 : RNA degradation..
Done pathway 3 : MAPK signaling pathway - plant..
Done pathway 4 : Plant hormone signal transduct..
Done pathway 5 : Sulfur relay system..
Done pathway 6 : SNARE interactions in vesicula..
Done pathway 7 : Autophagy..
Done pathway 8 : Protein processing in endoplas..
Done pathway 9 : Plant-pathogen interaction..
Done pathway 10 : Circadian rhythm - plant..> 

res[, -12]

Name ID pSize NDE pNDE         tA pPERT       pG pGFdr pGFWER    Status
1 Plant hormone signal transduction 04075     4   4    1 -0.4086641 0.812     
0.981103     1      1 Inhibited
2 Protein processing in endoplasmic reticulum 04141     1   1    1    
0.0000000    NA 1.000000     1      1 Inhibited
```

While these results are exciting, I have some questions to make sure this output is correct:

1) What is the printed 'Done' pathway list, and why does it print only 10 pathways rather than all 134 pathways?

2) For Protein processing in endoplasmic reticulum in HC and CP results, why is this pathway in the list although pPERT = 'NA.'   So, how come the other 'Done' pathways (e.g. RNA transport, RNA degradation, Autophagy....) do not show up in the res output? Is this Protein processing in endoplasmic reticulum pathway considered significant if tA = 0, pG = 1 and pPERT = 'NA'?

3) I didn't expect pSize and NDE to be equal to each other, and so all the pNDEs are equal to 1...Why is pSize and NDE the same value?

4)  The fold change values for the 243 HC DE probes dataset range from +3.25 to -4.38. Since I'm starting with gene probesets with an adj.P.Value < 0.001, I lowered the nB value to say 100, but the results are identical as if I used nB =2000. This is also true when I did this on the 127 CP DE probes dataset. Why is this?

Thanks for reading this as I tried to give as much info as possible while being succinct. I'm trying to understand this SPIA package in a bit more detail than explained in the vignette and ref manual.
Hope to hear from you soon.
Thanks,
Franklin

Answer (score 0):

The response to this post can be found on Bioconductor:
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/90756/